# SQUID-PRIVOXY-TOR issue

Tags: tor, squid, privoxy

I successfully installed my SQUID-PRIVOXY-TOR chain to let some PC navigate over the TOR sites.

My SQUID version is 3.5.20;
my Privoxy version is 3.0.33;
my TOR version is 0.3.5.18.

I face with both V2 and V3 onion addresses, referring to V2 the onion addresses 16-char long and to V3 the onion addresses 56-char long; all ports are open, the services are up and running and configurations seem to be good.

What sounds strange to me is that I successfully navigate to a 56-char long address, but I can't with 16-char long address.
In privoxy log I read:

```
Tor[8718]: Service address [scrubbed] has an invalid length. Expected 56 but got 16.
Tor[8718]: Invalid onion hostname [scrubbed]; rejecting
```

**Can TOR 0.3.5.18 handle old 16-char long onion websites?
Or, have I rollback to some older TOR version to handle them?**

With my new configuration are 16-char long onion address useless or can I continue to use them in some way?

thank you all for any advice,

Pietro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V2 addresses are useless. Their EOL was October 15th, 2021.

https://blog.torproject.org/v2-deprecation-timeline/

Pietro